# Matplotlib- Coloring NaN using Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, nan, matplotlib-basemap, colormap

I have a map of mean February sea ice concentration around Antarctica for 1979-2014 where I set values over land to NaN (they were originally -1e30 since obviously you can't have sea ice values on land). Due to the resolution, some of the NaN blocks along the coast extend over parts of the ocean, and the weird thing is instead of being left white, they're filled as if their value is the maximum negative value allowed by the colorbar. When I plot the data w/o the Basemap, it's upside-down, but the NaN's are not filled.

1. Any idea why the basemap plot is filling NaN's instead of leaving them uncolored?
2. Is there a way I can fill the NaN's with a custom color? I'd like to fill them with the same light gray used for the continent fill.

## Import packages

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, cm
%matplotlib inline
```

## Import & extract data

```
file = Dataset("HadISST_ice.nc")
ice  = file.variables['sic'][1309:1737] #Feb 1979-Sept 2014
lat  = file.variables['latitude'][:]
lon  = file.variables['longitude'][:]
print ice.shape
```

Output:

```
(428, 180, 360)
```

## Create mask for nan values

```
ice_filt = np.asarray(ice)                  #copies data to new array
missing_values_indices = ice_filt < -8000000 #finds where values are below threshold
ice_filt[missing_values_indices] = np.nan     #changes values below threshold to NaN
print ice[0,90,125], ice_filt[0,90,125]
```

Output:

```
-- nan
```

## Calculate February mean

```
febice = np.zeros((35,180,360))
a=0
for i in np.arange(35):
    febice[i,:,:] = ice_filt[a,:,:]
    a = a+12
febice_mean = np.nanmean(febice,axis=0)
#febice_mean = np.flipud(febice_mean)
print febice_mean.shape
```

Output:

```
(180, 360)
```

## Plot w/o basemap

```
plt.contourf(febice_mean)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

## Plot with basemap

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,14))
m = Basemap(projection='spstere',lon_0=270,boundinglat=-55.,resolution='l') #create basemap & specify res
m.drawcoastlines(color='grey')
m.fillcontinents(color='0.8')
m.drawcountries()
meshlon,meshlat = np.meshgrid(lon,lat) 
x, y = m(meshlon,meshlat)                                                 #assign 2D arrays to new variables
sic = m.pcolormesh(x,y,febice_mean,cmap=plt.cm.Blues_r,vmin=0.,vmax=1)
cbar=m.colorbar(sic,size="3%",)
cbar.set_label('Sea ice fractional coverage')
plt.title('Antarctic Sea Ice Cover (1979-2014 February Mean)',fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

[image]

PS: I know the NaN fill seems nitpicky here, but it's much more noticeable & a bit distracting when I plot for the North Pole.

Comment: Try using different map projection (simple projection). I think the projection process involves computing a cell while considering surrounding cell values. Try simple map projection and see the result. For polar plot, I don't know of any simple projection which can generate proportional and pretty plot.

Comment: 1) A non-polar projection would be bad for what I'm trying to show.
2) I tried a Mercator anyway and the issue was the same.

Comment: I would try to uase numpys masked arrays instead of using NaNs for masking out Land,